# Orchard Theme in WebForms

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

Generally in Orchard MVC we use to decorate the [Themed] attribute for themes above the controller. But here I'm using ASP.NET WebForms. I'm unable to get the orchard theme. I had decorated the attribute as follows :

```
 [Themed]
public partial class EmployeeInfo : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Themed or not themed, WebForms are not supported in Orchard.

Comment: By for my custom link I had provided the param link of my aspx page it is able to redirect even. That's why I thought there would be a process of themeing too.  Any way are you sure that [themed] is not possible with aspx page ???

Comment: Then How to get my webforms.aspx page to my orchard app ?

Comment: I'm not saying that it's impossible, but that it's unsupported. It's a really, really bad idea. Just use Razor, which is the supported way of building views in Orchard. Do not try to put WebForms pages in Orchard, it's a waste of time.

Comment: Thank a lot. I'm thinking about webforms y bcoz mean : Already my whole app was built in webforms. so now if I go with mvc, again need to work a lot. So, I'm in search for the web forms in orchard themes, In stead of working on MVC views. Is my approach is wrong ? Please suggest what to do ?

Comment: Yes, your approach is wrong. If you've already built the application in WebForms, why use Orchard at all? Orchard is built on MVC, not WebForms.